# Meteor 1.6 Coffeescript: reserved word 'import'

Tags: meteor, import, coffeescript

i`m using Meteor 1.6. with coffeescript package and when i use 'import' to import npm package, i have this error.

```
Errors prevented startup:

   While processing files with coffeescript (for target web.browser):
   client/pages/list/itemsList.coffee:1:1: reserved word 'import'
```

Here my packages file:

```
meteor-base@1.3.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.5       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.4.2                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4 # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library
coffeescript
dynamic-import
standard-minifier-css@1.4.0   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.3.1    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.7.0                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers

shell-server@0.3.1            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command   
ecmascript  
check
ejson
jquery
less
random
rate-limit
yasaricli:slugify
kadira:flow-router
kadira:blaze-layout    
momentjs:moment    
accounts-base
accounts-ui
accounts-password
service-configuration
accounts-facebook
session
http    
email    
patrickml:swal
raix:handlebar-helpers    
ostrio:files    
ethereum:web3
tap:i18n    
meteorhacks:ssr
```

Please, help. I don`t know what to do.. I have latest updated coffeescript and ecmascript packages.

Update:
after `meteor update` i have this result

```
The following top-level dependencies were not updated to the very latest
version available:
 * coffeescript 1.0.17 (2.2.1_1 is available)
```

Solved:
This is due to the package tap:i18n it has in the dependencies is such a version of coffeescript

Comment: Some different bheavior if you pleace the cofeescript package below the ecmascript package in the list?

Comment: I tried differently, but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

You also need the `modules` package.

```
meteor add modules
```

Comment: Many thanks for the advice. Indeed, this is logical. To my surprise, after the addition of this module nothing has changed. The error is still relevant

Comment: Your `coffeescript` package version is very old. The package added support for modules in 1.2.5, back in 2016.

Comment: This is due to the package tap:i18n it has in the dependencies is such a version of coffeescript